# Python imports not working after interrupt

Tags: python, tensorflow

I was running a Tensorflow code then interrupted it via `ctrl+c`. I then re-ran it immediately after (without making any adjustments to the code) and am now unable to import anything, even Tensorflow. I looked through some internet searches for a similar problem but have yet to find any that is related.

Re-running the script:

```
(env_maskrcnn) haziq@vita-workstation2:~/human-pose-3d$ ./run2.sh
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "src/predict_3dpose.py", line 13, in <module>
    import h5py
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'h5py'
Error in sys.excepthook:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/apport_python_hook.py", line 63, in apport_excepthook
    from apport.fileutils import likely_packaged, get_recent_crashes
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/apport/__init__.py", line 5, in <module>
    from apport.report import Report
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/apport/report.py", line 30, in <module>
    import apport.fileutils
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/apport/fileutils.py", line 23, in <module>
    from apport.packaging_impl import impl as packaging
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/apport/packaging_impl.py", line 24, in <module>
    import apt
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/apt/__init__.py", line 23, in <module>
    import apt_pkg
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'apt_pkg'

Original exception was:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "src/predict_3dpose.py", line 13, in <module>
    import h5py
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'h5py'
```

Launching Python 3 to import Tensorflow:

```
(env_maskrcnn) haziq@vita-workstation2:~/human-pose-3d$ python3
Python 3.7.1 (default, Oct 22 2018, 11:21:55)
[GCC 8.2.0] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import tensorflow as tf
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tensorflow'
Error in sys.excepthook:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/apport_python_hook.py", line 63, in apport_excepthook
    from apport.fileutils import likely_packaged, get_recent_crashes
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/apport/__init__.py", line 5, in <module>
    from apport.report import Report
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/apport/report.py", line 30, in <module>
    import apport.fileutils
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/apport/fileutils.py", line 23, in <module>
    from apport.packaging_impl import impl as packaging
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/apport/packaging_impl.py", line 24, in <module>
    import apt
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/apt/__init__.py", line 23, in <module>
    import apt_pkg
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'apt_pkg'
```

Following the instructions given by Manish Dash, I checked the path that Python is pointing to. I am using Python 3 and it looks like it isn't not pointing to the correct path. I also checked the folder `/home/haziq/env_maskrcnn/bin/` but did not see a `python3` file. What could have happened and how do I fix it?

```
haziq@vita-workstation2:~$ source env_maskrcnn/bin/activate
(env_maskrcnn) haziq@vita-workstation2:~$ which python
/home/haziq/env_maskrcnn/bin/python
(env_maskrcnn) haziq@vita-workstation2:~$ which python3
/usr/bin/python3
```

Comment: Are you using virtualenvs?

Comment: @ManishDash yes I am using virtualenvs and am in the correct environment

Comment: Try starting a new terminal. Go into your environment and type `which python`. Is it pointing to the correct virtualenv path?

Comment: @ManishDash hello, I updated my findings on my original post. It looks like it isnt pointing to the correct path. I also can't find a python3 file in the virtualenv bin folder. What should I do now?

Comment: How did you create the environment? Is it python 2.7 or 3? you can check by just type `python` and note the version it tells.

Comment: @ManishDash I created the virtual environment through the command 'virtualenv env_maskrcnn'. Just typing python with the virtual environment activated tells me that its version is 2.7.15rc1. I manually installed tensorflow and other stuffs for python3 through pip3.